# SSRS-How to Get the Custom Created Field in the Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report having fields A, B, C and D.

A and B are from the data set ,

Value of C is A+B ,

D is percentage of A .

How can i get the custom added Field C in the expression of D ,so that i can calculate percentage for A .

Thanks In Advance .

Answer (score 0):

You can create field C at the dataset level as a calculated field and then use it in the expression of D.

**[Here is a link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207055.aspx)**